# Ios app that starts when a Local Region event occurs

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, location, core-location

I'm trying to develop an app that when i enter in a Local Region created before, notify this event. I've read a lot of discussion, but i'm still confused. I'm developing this app with the help of this community, because i'm also very new to swift. The app developed works very well if is active or in background, but it doesn't work if it is closed. Infact i want that the s.o. wakes my app (for doing some stuff, like notifications) when the iphone enters in the local region created before. Reading the apple's documentation, i have figure it out that the lauchOptions matters with my problem. So above, i post the code of the application function in my AppDelegate class.

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
     [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     // Override point for customization after application 
    launch.

    registerForPushNotifications()

    if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {
        if locationManager == nil {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.delegate = self
            locationManager?.distanceFilter = 10
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            Logger.write(text: "app opened by s.o.", to: logFile)
        }
    } else {
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.distanceFilter = 10
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
        else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied {
        }
        else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

I've implemented this code, according to other discussion found, but as told before the string "app opened by s.o." never being wrote on my logFile. How can i solve this problem? thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just print-debug your code.

```
print("registered for push notifications")
if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {
    print(locationManager)
    if locationManager == nil {
        ...
```

You should see "registered for push notifications" and then whatever the locationManager is. Maybe it is not nil so the Logger is not even executed

Comment: Yes! you're right! Now it works! in fact, the locationManager is always nil when the app starts in that way! thank you!